# How do you use a for loop inside of the callback function of the filter method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

This code returns the correct array but I am cheating inside of the `arrayFilter` function.  By using `matchItem[0]` and `matchItem[1]` I am hard coding the use of only 2 filter items.  If there are less than 2, the test will fail, and if there are more than 2, the extra items will not be filtered.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  var destroyerArgsAmount = arguments.length;
  var matchArr = arguments[0];       
  var newArr = [];

  var matchItems = []; 
  for(i = 1; i < destroyerArgsAmount; i++) {
    matchItems.push(arr[i]);
  }

  function arrayFilter(val) {
    if(val != matchItems[0] && val != matchItems[1]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  arr = matchArr.filter(arrayFilter);      
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Why does a for loop not work in this situation?

```
for(i = 0; i < matchItems.length; i++) {      
      if(matchItems[i] != value) {
        return value;
      }
```

This loop does not work when placed into the `arrayFilter` function

Can someone explain to me why and then get me on the correct path to how this is done?  I figure this will be an important thing to master since there are many methods employed this way like: filter, map, forEach and many more I don't know about yet.

Comment: This is actually very confusing, are you trying to filter the first array passed in, and if so why are you using the values from it as a filter, and not the second and third argument?

Comment: @adeneo Put your original answer back up.  I had a return statement below all of my code that i didn't see.  You were first and correct so i give a check to you.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/asdkzf98/**

Comment: Your `for` loop returns true if the `value` is different from *any* element in `matchItems`, but your first version returns true if the `value` is different from *all* elements in `matchItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexOf and return the result

```
function arrayFilter(val) {
   return matchItems.indexOf(val) === -1;
}
```

I would think maybe you're looking for something more like this

```
function destroyer() {
    var args     = [].slice.call(arguments),
        matchArr = args.shift();

    return matchArr.filter(function(item) {
        return args.every(function(item2) {
            return item !== item2;
        });
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/asdkzf98/1/)

Comment: I am sure there are many ways but i don't want to change my code to something i don't understand.  My code = beginner level
Thanks for the `indexOf` i will read up on it now.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure the results you're trying to achieve since you haven't explained it but, I'm assuming from your code your function is trying to `filter` all arguments passed after the first argument `array`.  Like this:

```
function destroyer (arr) {
  // You can use slice to grab all arguments after the first index in arguments
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  return arr.filter(function (item) {
    // filter anything not found in the arguments list
    // indexOf will return -1 if not found
    return args.indexOf(item) < 0;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you seem to need is a way to check if a value is in an Array.

As mentioned by @adeneo, if `val` is a primitive value (string, number, etc) or an object that should be compared by reference, the solution is as simple as

```
matchItems.indexOf(val)
```

which returns a positive number (the index) if `val` is one of the items in `matchItems` and `-1` otherwise.

---

If your use case is slightly more complicated, for example if matchItems contains objects and you want to see if an object with a particular property is in it, you can use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var found = matchItems.some(function(item){
  return item === val; // use the apropriate comparison here
});
```

---

Your full code would be:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var matchItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return arr.filter(function(a) {
    return !matchItems.some(function(b){
      return a === b;
    });
  });
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, but it would be a lot more useful to accompany it with a comment explaining the reason.

Comment: I up voted you. don't know why someone down voted.  Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: @Dominofoe Could be because the initial version filtered the wrong elements. Without a comment, i'll never know though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also doing the free code camp's challenges! This code passed the challenge:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    var arr = arguments[0];
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j < arguments.length; j++) {
          if (arr[i] === arguments[j]) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
          } 
        }
      }
    return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```